# Why do we don't write units with MAE or RSME for regression problem ? If I wish to write the units when how do I identify the units for them?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I have referred many research paper but no one is talking about the units of the metrics. Do MAE , RMSE etc have some units ?

Answer (score 0):

In general evaluation measures don't have any unit. Many of them actually represent proportions of instances (like accuracy, precision, recall).
But  it's true that error evaluation measures are different, as they represent a value based on the target variable.

Mean Absolute Error (MAE) is the average across instances of the absolute difference between the predicted and gold standard value. So this difference has the same unit as the original target value: for example, if the system predicts an income in dollars then the difference between the predicted and true value is also in dollars.

Answer (score 0):

RMSE and MAE do have units. In fact, they have the same units. (Determining why that’s the case is a useful exercise.) You determine those units by considering the units of your $y$. If $y$ is measured in dollars, euros, kilometers, or days, each of those metrics will be measured in dollars, euros, kilometers, or days, respectively.

There are times when you do want to consider the units on those metrics, such as, “Boss, we’re crushing it! The model only misses house prices by an average of a few cents,” or, “No, lazy subcontractor, we’re not paying you for developing a model that misses commute times by an average of three days.” In the material you’re reading, however, I can think of two reasons why the units are omitted.

1. The units are implied by the units of $y$, so there is no ambiguity, and omitting the units saves space.
2. Models of the same $y$ are being compared, so no matter the units, the model with the lower loss value is superior (assuming proper validation, which is a topic for a separate question or a [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/331933039X)).